# How to express the projector on the coherent ground state in terms of positions and momenta?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematics

In [this paper](http://cds.cern.ch/record/531380/files/0112090.pdf) the author writes in (19) how one can express $|0\rangle \langle 0|$ in term of the ladder operators a and $a^\dagger$ . It is $:\exp(-a^\dagger a):$ (the :: are the symbols of normal ordering)

Can we express it in terms of X and P?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, normally (up to coefficients)
\begin{equation}
X = (a + a^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}, P = -i(a-a^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}
\end{equation}
so one can express $X$ and $P$ from these equations and substitute to the normal-ordered expansion
\begin{equation}
:\exp(a^\dagger a): = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(a^\dagger)^na^n}{n!}.
\end{equation}